# file.get() returning random numbers after a loop C++

Tags: c++, file-io, for-loop

I am working on a program that reads a series of ints from a text file into a 2D array. 

The file contains 40 lines of 81 numbers that have no spaces between them.

The problem is that when I cout the array after the loop has finished, it is outputting 2 random numbers in `array[0][0]` and `array[0][1]` before the expected output. I think it has to do with the newline/carriage return characters. The first iteration of the loop runs perfectly. Here is the code:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int array[9][9];

  //Open file:

  fstream ifile;

  ifile.open("numbers.txt", ios::in);
  if (ifile.fail())
    {
      cout << "Could not open numbers.txt" << endl;
      return -1;
    }

   while (!ifile.eof())
    {
      for(int i=0; i<9; i++)
      {   
    for(int j=0; j<9; j++)
    {
       int n = ifile.get();
              if(isdigit(n)) 
            {
                  array[i][j] = n - '0';
        }

          cout<<"array ["<<i<<"]["<<j<<"] is "<<array[i][j]<<endl;
      } 
      } cout<<"This is a test"<<endl;
    }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: How does your input file look like?

Comment: 1) You don't test to see if `file.get()` succeeds. 2) You increment `j` even if `n` is not a digit, and 3) **Please** provide a short, complete program that demonstrates the error you are having. See http://sscce.org/.

Comment: @KornelKisielewicz it's a file with 40 lines of 81 numbers that have no spaces between them

Comment: @Robᵩ That's only a snippet of code. The program is quite long so I only included the bit that was causing problems.

Comment: And you tested this snippet by itself?

Comment: @adohertyd - I'm **not** suggesting that you give us "the program". As you can see at http://sscce.org, it would be helpful for you to give us *some* program that is complete, short, and demonstrates the problem. You can create such a program by starting with your program, removing bits and continuously testing the result. Once you have the shortest possible program that still fails, post **that**.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Comment: @BenVoigt Not a duplicate post completely different problem

Comment: @adohertyd If it's a file of 40 lines of 81 digits, then you're going to have a lot of difficulty reading it into an array of 9x9.

Comment: @JamesKanze I'm reading each 81 digit line into a 9x9 array, processing that particular line(the process is not included in my code) and then reading the next line in etc. to end of file

Comment: @adohertyd: The fact that you think this is a completely different problem explains why you haven't gotten it working yet.

Comment: @BenVoigt My problem occurs after the first loop takes place. eof isn't causing the problem I'm experiencing. If I change the while loop to for(k=0; k<5; k++) the problem remains the same.

Comment: @adohertyd In which case, the best solution is probably to use `std::getline` to read the line into a string, and then process the string for the individual characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The random numbers appear because you increment `j` regardless of whether you write to `grid[i][j]`.

Try replacing your inner loop with:

```
for(int j=0; j<9; )
{
  int n = file.get();
  if(!file) break;
  if(isdigit(n))
  {
    array[i][j] = n - '0';
    cout<<"array ["<<i<<"]["<<j<<"] is "<<array[i][j]<<endl;
    j++;
  }
  cout<<"grid ["<<i<<"]["<<j<<"] is "<<grid[i][j]<<endl;
}
```

Comment: It was worth a great deal. I've edited my answer. It provides a correct solution now.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand the purpose of the outer loop at all.  First, `file`
will never be equal to `eof()`, or...  What is `eof()`, any way?
Second, if you've actually written `while ( !file.eof() )`, this could
explain the fact that some of the elements get overwritten.  There will
likely be some trailing characters (a new line, at least) after the last
digit, so you'll reenter the loop again.

And you're incrementing the indexes even when the character you read is
not a digit.  If the data is 9 lines of 9 digits, you'll end up with 9
cells in `grid` which haven't been initialized, and 9 characters that
haven't been read from the file once you've finished the inner two
iterations.  So you'll enter the outer loop again, reading these
characters.  Some of which will be digits, so you'll end up overwriting
cells in `grid` that you've already written—this is probably the
effect you're observing.  Also that once you reach the end of the file,
`file.get()` will start returning `EOF`—typically -1.  That's
doubtlessly why your tests for `'\n'` and `'\r'` didn't work.

And these are just the problems with a correctly formatted file.  For a
correctly formatted file, just using `file >> n`, with `char n;` would
almost work; `operator>>` skips whitespace.  But you'd still enter the
outermost loop a second time, since `file.eof()` won't be reliable until
an input has failed.  You say "I have to use this", but your code can't
be made to work unless you change it.

Personally, I favor robust solutions, with lots of error checking.  I'd
use `std::getline()`, and I'd verify that each line contained exactly 9
digits.  Something like:

```
std::string line;
int i = 0;
while ( i < 9 && std::getline( file, line ) ) {
    if ( line.size() != 9 ) {
        throw FormatError( "wrong line length" );
    }
    for ( int j = 0; j != 9; ++ j ) {
        if ( ! isdigit( static_cast<unsigned char>( line[j] ) ) ) {
            throw FormatError( "illegal character" );
        }
        grid[i][j] = line[i] - '0';
    }
}
if ( i != 9 || std::getline( file, line ) ) {
    throw FormatError( "wrong line count" );
}
```

It wouldn't be too hard to use `file.get()`, and read one character at
at time, but you'd still want to check for `EOF` after each read:

```
for ( int i = 0; i != 9; ++ i ) {
    for ( int j = 0; j != 9; ++ j ) {
        int ch = file.get();
        if ( ch == EOF ) {
            throw FormatError( j == 0 
                                ? "line too short" 
                                : "too few lines" );
        }
        if ( !isdigit( ch ) ) {
            throw FormatError( "illegal character" );
        }
        grid[i][j] = ch - '0';
    }
    int ch = file.get();
    if ( ch != '\n' ) {
        throw FormatError( ch == EOF ? "too few lines" : "line too long" );
    }
}
if ( file.get() != EOF ) {
    throw FormatError( "too many lines" );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`eof` isn't set when you reach the end of the file, it's set after a read fails.  And the data from that last read is of course invalid, because it failed.  Your current code uses the invalid data...

---

Beyond that, `file != eof()` is all kinds of wrong.  It shouldn't even compile, because there is no `::eof()` function, and `iostream::eof()` needs an object.  `file != EOF` might compile, but then `file` will be converted to bool and promoted to int (either `0` or `1`), it will never be equal to `EOF` (`-1`).  What you meant was `!file.eof()`, but that's also wrong for the reason given above.

Comment: Your statements are true of course. But *that* bug doesn't explain his complaint. Namely "2 random numbers in `array[0][0]` and `array[0][1]`".

Comment: @Rob: Sure it does, he calls `file.get()` many times before he checks `eof()`.

Comment: @Rob It does, because by advancing his indexes faster than he consumes digits, he ends up taking the outer loop twice, overwriting some of the earlier digits.